# On Form Submit event is not getting trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I have write one script to get the data from one sheet to anther. Script is running successfully when I run manually but after I added a trigger on form submit it is not running. Other triggers are working only On From Submit is not working.

Please find my Script for reference.

```
function SubmitData(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS = ss.getSheetByName("Script_Data");//Form Sheet
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("Script_RAW");//Data Sheet

  // Input Values
  var values = [[formSS.getRange("A2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("B2").getValue(),
  formSS.getRange("C2").getValue(),
  formSS.getRange("D2").getValue(),
  formSS.getRange("E2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("F2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("G2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("H2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("I2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("J2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("K2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("L2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("M2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("N2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("O2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("P2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("Q2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("R2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("S2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("T2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("U2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("V2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("W2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("X2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("Y2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("Z2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("AA2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("AB2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("AC2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("AD2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("AE2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("AF2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("AG2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("AH2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("AI2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("AJ2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("AK2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("AL2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("AM2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("AN2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("AO2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("AP2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("AQ2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("AR2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("AS2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("AT2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("AU2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("AV2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("AW2").getValues(),
  formSS.getRange("AX2").getValues(),
  ]];
  datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 50).setValues(values);
}
```

[Snapshot trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPRFv.png)

Please help me on above scenario.

You can connect with me personally on pritam.joshi@gmail.com and +91 9850829782.

Thanks
Pritam Joshi

Comment: Which trigger did you enable the one for the form or the one for the spreadsheet? Since you are using getActiveSpreadsheet() I assume you want the one for the spreadsheet

Comment: If it is the one for the spreadsheet, do you realize that the event object contains all of the information for each submission inside of the event object.  So there is no need to access the linked sheet directly and using getValues() for individual cells is not how it was intended to be using.  getValues() returns a 2 d array not a single value.

Comment: If you must access the sheet atleast use getValues the way it was intended to be used. Try `let values = formSS.getRange("A2:AX2").getValues(); sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1,1,values.length,values[0]length).setValues(values);` If you wish to eleminate some cells in the final data transfer you can alway use map.

Answer (score 0):

```
function SubmitData(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("Script_Data");//Form Sheet
  var sh2 = ss.getSheetByName("Script_RAW");//Data Sheet
  var values = sh1.getRange("A2:AX2").getValues();
  sh2.getRange(sh2.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

But if you want the submitted data:

```
let arr = e.values.slice();
arr.shift();//eliminate timestamp
sh2.getRange(sh2.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, arr.length).setValues([arr]);//post answers to questions
```

Please put this code into the first line of the trigger handler function: `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));`

Just to make sure that I understand the problem can you load this script into the editor and save it and then run it and take an image of the output and post in into your question.

```
function displayProjectTriggers() {
  var tA=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  var html="<style>th,td{border:1px solid black;padding:2px;margin:2px;}</style><table><tr><th>Handler Function</th><th>Trigger Type</th><th>Unique ID</th><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
  for(let i=0;i<tA.length;i++) {
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td><input type="button" value="Delete" onClick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(){google.script.run.displayProjectTriggers();}).deleteTrigger(\'%s\');" /></td></tr>',tA[i].getHandlerFunction(),tA[i].getEventType(),tA[i].getUniqueId(),tA[i].getHandlerFunction());
  }
  html+='</table><br /><input type="button" value="Close" onClick="google.script.host.close();" />';
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setWidth(800);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Project Triggers');
}
```

Comment: Hi Cooper, Thanks to update on my query. Acutely there is not have any issue to run the script. I have add trigger 'on form submit' to run the script once the data added in spreadsheet. That trigger is not working.

Comment: Have you checked your execution logs

Comment: Refer to the last entry in my answer.